# Nginx works with IP address but not domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to configure an nginx server with TLS. It successfully works when I use the IP address, but not with the domain name.

For instance, https://111.111.111.111/ works, but https://example.com does not (IP and domain are redacted).

```
DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem.
```

Almost the entire configuration is the default other than listening on port 433 and adding the SSL certificates.

Here's my entire config (with all the boilerplate comments removed).

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my-key.pem;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

## Debug steps

I don't have an exhaustive list of everything I've tried, but here are some of the things I remember:

- Double-checked the DNS on Cloudflare points to the correct IP address (it's an A record pointing to a IPv4 address)
- Double-checked the DNS propogated
- `ping https://example.com` resolves to the correct IP address
- Turned all firewalls off
- Tried on several browsers on multiple devices
- Ensured this is not a `www.example.com` vs `example.com` mismatch

Comment: It's very likely that you tried this already, but just in case, have you flushed your devices' DNS caches?

Comment: "devices' DNS caches" may include your router's cache as well.